# SignalR MethodAccessException

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i got this error when i try to debug  a simple signalr app

> Attempt to access the method
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.DependencyResolverExtensions.InitializePerformanceCounters(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver,
>   System.String, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' by the method
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.RouteExtensions.MapHubs(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection,
>   System.String, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver)' failed

=== Edited [Added more INFO] ===

ok added SignalR by typing this on Nuget Consolse

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
```

i added a repo [here](https://github.com/whebz/SignalRTest)

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting exception message to SO? Google for example? SignalR Wiki?

Comment: before asking here.. i looked at signalr wiki.. i did the same thing from asp.net signalr tutorial.

Comment: You need to provide more information, not only a exception message, otherwise the post have a great chance to getting closed by admins.
Try to explain what have you tried and provide some source code, if you have any.

Comment: i added a repo. please check it above

Comment: You get this on localhost?

Comment: Getting this problem too, i installed signalR 1.0.0-alpha2 along with ASP.NET SignalR Hosting for ASP.NET 1.0.0-alpha2 and im getting same exception on `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()`

Comment: @dfowler I'm getting same error, I installed the latest rc1 into an asp.net mvc 4 with .net 4.5 runtime.

Comment: @dfowler yes.. but i'm using iis express not visual studio webserver

Comment: Same error here, just install SignalR of nuget (1hr ago), added to an existing asp.net mvc3 app. Added a single Hub, and ran the code, getting the same error! EDIT: Actually not exactly the same error, will post a new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.AspNet" version="1.0.0-alpha2" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Common" version="1.0.0-alpha2" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  </packages>
```

the versions installed were mixed between alpha and rc1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by changing the .csproj file ...

It had (may be MVC 3 or so):

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};
```

into MVC 4 project:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};
```

Comment: where did you get that guid? i tried to do the same but it didn't work for me

Comment: That guid is for MVC 4, make sure you have RTM version of MVC 4/3 installed, create a sample project ... and copy it from the project .csproj

Comment: What packages do you have installed?