# Fresh SignalR install fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 site, and have just added SignalR to the mix (off nuget).

I've added a Hubs folder, and a single class into that folder (inheriting from the Hub class).

I'm working in VS2010 and running on IIS Express on localhost. Hitting F5 gives me this:

> Attempt by method
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.RouteExtensions.MapHubs(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection,
>   System.String, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver)' to
>   access method
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.DependencyResolverExtensions.InitializePerformanceCounters(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver,
>   System.String, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' failed.

In the Start method of the RegisterHubs class. Any ideas? I've done a google search and all it came up with was a link to this question [MethodAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973425/signalr-methodaccessexception) (looks a bit similar).

Additional info: Replacing the RC1 with the older Alpha 2 solves the problem, but..

Comment: Can you file a bug on github with the stacktrace?